# How can I Split a list in python to get a new list with elements to the left of the delimiter instead of the right

Tags: python, split

I want to split this python list (originalList):

```
['"car_type":"STANDARD","price":725842', 
'"car_type":"LUXURY","price":565853', 
'"car_type":"PEOPLE_CARRIER","price":239081', 
'"car_type":"LUXURY_PEOPLE_CARRIER","price":661624', 
'"car_type":"MINIBUS","price":654172']
```

to give me this list (pricesList):

```
[725842, 565853, 239081, 661624, 654172]
```

I tried this line of code below to split the list named originalList:

```
pricesList = [i.split("price:")[0] for i in originalList]
```

The outcome is a list with the same number of elements, but each element contains the car_type only, in short the splitting has removed everything to the left of the delimiter. How can I change my code above or even replace to obtain in the new list elements with the values to the left of the delimiter and everything to the right removed?

Comment: use `pricesList = [i.split("price:")[1] for i in originalList]`

Comment: Just curious based on how you have this setup, are you interested in using dictionaries?

Answer (score 2):

You forget the double-quotes `"` that are part of your delimiter, then pick the wrong index (`0`) which is *before* the split, and finally, you do not cast to `int`. You can do the following to get the desired output:

```
>>> [int(i.split('"price":')[-1]) for i in originalList]
[725842, 565853, 239081, 661624, 654172]
```

Answer (score 0):

schwobaseggl answer is good, here is a possible alternative using json library (I guess original list comes from json processing)

```
import json
list(map(lambda x:json.loads('{'+x+'}')['price'],originalList))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import json

n = ['"car_type":"STANDARD","price":725842',
'"car_type":"LUXURY","price":565853',
'"car_type":"PEOPLE_CARRIER","price":239081',
'"car_type":"LUXURY_PEOPLE_CARRIER","price":661624',
'"car_type":"MINIBUS","price":654172']

print [json.loads("{"+str(i)+"}")["price"] for i in n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

pricesList = [int(originalList[i].split(",")[1].split(":")[1]) for i in range(0,len(l1))]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

If you change to `.split(':')` you can just take the `[-1]` item, that will represent the numbers at the end

```
lista = [ 
    '"car_type":"STANDARD","price":725842', 
    '"car_type":"LUXURY","price":565853', 
    '"car_type":"PEOPLE_CARRIER","price":239081', 
    '"car_type":"LUXURY_PEOPLE_CARRIER","price":661624', 
    '"car_type":"MINIBUS","price":654172'
]

new_lista = []

for i in range(len(lista)):
    lista[i] = lista[i].split(':')
    new_lista.append(lista[i][-1])

print(new_lista)
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 split.py 
> ['725842', '565853', '239081', '661624', '654172']
> ```